# How can I get to see the files I have uploaded to Heroku?

Tags: git, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

How can I get to see the files I have uploaded to Heroku?

Comment: That's unbelievably vague. Do you mean you created a new app on Heroku and you want to know how to access it?

Answer (score 1):

You can clone it using the same URL you used to push the code: `git clone git@heroku.com:your-app.git`.

Answer (score 0):

After a git push, your remote tracking branches should be up top date with what is on the server.

```
git log origin/master
```

should show you the latest that was pushed up if you are using the master branch.

Hope this helps